# csvReader is skipping the first alphabet of every row of fist column while reading from a csv file

Tags: java, csv

I wrote a csvReader method in Java.
Everything seems to work fine, but it is just skipping the very first alphabet of every row in first column while printing the values. Here is my code =>

```
public static void csvReader(String fileName) {

    try {
        BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        fileReader.readLine();

        while (fileReader.read() > 0) {
            String line = fileReader.readLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(COMMA_DELIMETER);

            if (tokens.length > 0) {
                Student student = new Student(tokens[0], tokens[1], Integer.valueOf(tokens[2]),
                        Integer.valueOf(tokens[3]));
                students.add(student);
            }
        }

        students.forEach(System.out::println);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here "Student" is just a POJO class having firstName, lastName, id and age fields.  In am getting the output as =>

```
Student details : ID = 101 first name = ikhil Last name = Chaurasia age = 28
Student details : ID = 102 first name = adhna Last name = Chaurasia age = 28
```

Where the result should be like =>

```
Student details : ID = 101 first name = Nikhil Last name = Chaurasia age = 28
Student details : ID = 102 first name = Sadhna Last name = Chaurasia age = 28
```

The csv file content are shown below :

[image: csv_file.csv]

The toString method is implemented as shown below :

```
public String toString() {
    return "Student details : ID = "+id+ " first name = "+firstName+ " Last name = "+lastName+ " age = "+age;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what's the `toString()` method of `Student`?  From what you've put here, the processing looks right, which makes me question the retrieval.  Also, you can do a println just after `students.add()` with the output of the token split.

Comment: @Jason : Just updated the question to mention the toString method implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your `while` loop condition: `fileReader.read() > 0`.

This reads a single character every time you call it (such as 'N', 'S'), which causes the subsequent call to `readLine` to skip the first character.

Instead, just check the condition using `readLine`:

```java
String line;
while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] tokens = line.split(COMMA_DELIMETER);
  // do the rest of the stuff
}
```